# What is the life-cycle of CXF Interceptor?

Tags: rest, cxf, interceptor

What is the life-cycle of CXF Interceptor? Is only one instance created of each interceptor or new instances are created for each service invocation?

I need to write an Interceptor for RESTful services which requires some initialization and I do not want it to be performed each time the Interceptor is invoked.
What is the best approach to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to find any relevant documentation, but if you create Interceptor externally and pass the instance to CXF it will use it and will not create another instances.

For initialization part it is best to add @PostConstruct annotation (JEE5) on initializing method. The method will be invoked after the bean creation.

Comment: On server side: do I understand you correctly if it follows the lifecycle of the bean / servlet that implements the web service? So each time a bean is added to the pool (created) also an associated interceptor is created?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you meant a CXF interceptor. The official documentation can be found here: 
http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html

Here is a tutorial for integrating CXF with Restful servies: 
http://www.celinio.net/techblog/?p=637

Comment: Thanks, but it does not answer my question. The official documentation does not mention anything about the Interceptor life-cycle and many other important things.